# UML class diagram - what do I put the output type for a function that can return different output types?

Tags: python, uml

I have a function that returns a different output based on the converter function the user passes in. Basically the output of the function will be the same as the output of the converter function. I know it's not really a proper function since the output type isn't constant but python allows it and so I want to take advantage of it. How will label the output for my function when I don't know its type?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dealt with this as instructor a couple of times.  First, I have the student explain *why* it's a good idea to return different types from a function.  This usually solves the problem: that unit needs a cleaner design.

In two cases, the team *did* have a valid reason for the return variety.  In that case, I had them use any practical, readable notation, such as

```
{ int | exception }
```

The formal UML notation we used didn't suggest that this was acceptable in "pure" UML, but there was also no authority to enforce the standards that was higher than me (the person assigning grades).

Comment: With emphasis on the last sentence.